# How to check what is the most common value in a specific index in list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of list of integers:

```
ls = [[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[1,1,3]]
```

and I want to end up with a list that has `len(ls[0])` elements, and each element is the element that appears most in that index. In this example the result would be `[1 (appears in first&last), 2 (appears in first&second), 3 (appears in all)]`

I tried using loops and was hoping for a built-in like `all` (most?)

```
ls = [[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[1,1,3]]

ls2=[]

ls2 =[item for sub in ls for item in sub]

ls2
Out[40]: [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3]

ls3=[]

for item in len(ls):...
```

What would be the way to do so?

Comment: Have you made any attempts that you can show (and describe how it failed)?

Comment: What have you tried? As asked, this is basically a "write my code for me" question. There are decent solutions involving `Counter` and it's `most_common` method if you need a starting point; `operator.itemgetter` and `map` might be used to optimize (though a plain generator expression would work just fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my (alternative solution) 2 cents:

```
>>> ls = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 3]]
>>> l_mc = [max(x, key=x.count) for x in zip(*ls)]
>>> l_mc
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `max(x, key=x.count)` takes runtime quadratic in the length of `x`, due to unnecessarily rescanning `x` for each `count` call. A `Counter`-based solution takes usual-case linear time.

Comment: I said, "good to know". Moderators, please refrain from randomly deleting people's comments.

Answer (score 3):

Transpose your list, apply Counters.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> ls = [[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[1,1,3]]
>>> counts = [Counter(x) for x in zip(*ls)]
>>> [c.most_common(1)[0][0] for c in counts]
[1, 2, 3]
```

This will pick an arbitrary number if two numbers share the highest occurence for the same index.

Comment: arbitrary number - from the numbers with the highest occurrence for that index? Is it possible to get a list of those numbers?

Comment: @CIsForCookies yes to both

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

ls = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 3]]

print([max(x.items(), key = itemgetter(1))[0] for x in map(Counter, zip(*ls))])
# [1, 2, 3]
```